# Custom role for only one project on Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, firebase-analytics, google-iam

I want to add member into my Firebase project who can only see Firebase Crashlytics. And it should be for **one project.**

I have created custom role however I can't assign the role to only one project. No other information should be visible such as Analytics data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add project under IAM Role GCP.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).